# Envoy - rewrite hostname, keep wildcard subdomain

Tags: proxy, routes, envoyproxy

Simple question: I want to request my envoy with `foo.bar.com/myapp` and forward the traffic to `foo.fiz.net/myapp`. `foo` can be anything.

Could not find any examples. I tried to play with `regex_rewrite` and `host_rewrite` but could not find the right combination of options.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no sorry, we had to rethink our architecture